# Complex structures on Riemann surfaces

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, teichmueller-theory

Let $M$ be a Riemann surface and $[\alpha] \in H^{0,1}(M; T^{1,0} M) \simeq H^0(M;K^2)$.  Considering $\alpha$ as a map $T^{0,1} M \to T^{1,0} M$, the bundle
$$
\{v + \alpha(v) \mid v \in T^{0,1} M\} \subset T_{\mathbb{C}} M
$$
forms the (0,1) part of another complex structure on (the underlying real manifold of) $M$.  Is it true that every complex structure (modulo diffeomorphism) arises in this way?

I'm pretty sure this is true and very standard, so a good reference would be great.

---

EDIT

I should add that $\alpha$ must be sufficiently small so that its graph inside $T_{\mathbb C} M$ does not intersect the real tangent bundle $TM$.